# I am trying to get the index value of the list item selected

Tags: python, html, django, forms, list

## search.py

```
    <div class="container">
      <br>
      <div class="dropdown">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Names
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                {% for items in name %}
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'details' %}">{{ items }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
              </div> 
      </div>
```

name is a list which varies it can have 2 or 3 or n number of items  so i have used a for loop to display all the items in the drop down .now what i am trying to do is get the index of the dropdown item clicked .
for example i click the third item of the drop-down  i want to pass index of 2 to my views.py so when it redirects to the url "details.html" the data shown on the webpage will be pulled from a list in which i want to pass the index of the item clicked in the drop-down according to the index.

## views.py

```
    def details(request ):
        name = request.session.get("name")
        data = request.session.get("data")
        txns = data["drop-downindex"]["txns"]
        context ={"txns":txns ,"name1":name1}
        return render(request , "details.html", context )
```

a session is what i am using to store data i am basically making an API in another function and storing the json data in data variable which is a list
1)the data list contains txns details for various names(dropdown)
so when i click the 2nd item of the dropdown the index 1 should go in my data list and fetch txns for list item 2 or index 1

Comment: can you show your details view? is the index=2 same as items.pk? usually, we will use ```"{% url 'details'  pk=item.pk %}"``` to pass variable to views, and in views, you might have something like ```def details(request, pk)``` . BTW, you might want to use ```item``` rather than ```items```.

Comment: @ha-neul iI have edited post as you said now you can find the details view. I dont understand what you mean by pk =item.pk  . i will use item but i dont think i makes any difference . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using the enumerate method you can make the index value in list.

```
name =['a','b','c','d','e']
```

```
for key,value in enumerate(name):
      print(key , value)
```

**Output :**

```
         1 a
         2 b
         3 c
         4 d
         5 e
```

Comment: This is not what the OP's asking

Answer (score 0):

Change your URL so it accepts an index argument. Something like

```
url( r'^details/(?P<index>\d+)/$', myview, name='detail' )
```

Change your view to accept the index argument

Change your template to pass an index argument to `url`:

```
 <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'details' index=index %}">{{ items }}</a>
```

I'm not clear where that index argument comes from, but it'll be something in your view context. The canonical example is a detail view that accepts an object id, obtained by iterating a queryset in the template:

```
... href="{% url 'details' id=object.id %}"
```

If name is a list, you'd pass `name=enumerate(name)` to your template and the for-loop would be `{% for index,items in name %}`

Comment: all the the drop down items are a-tab the number of items in the drop down is equal to number of items in the name list, the number of items in the name list differs each time so the number of items in the drop down menu what i need is a way to tell my view that the 3rd or the 4th item or whatever index of the item that has been clicked once i pass or  receive the index in my view i will it to extract data from a  txns list using the index number that i get from my search.py or the drop-down index and accordingly show output on the details . html